Searching for emails in AWS Open search
I am pushing a lot of data in an AWS OpenSearch instance to easily search various strings. The data I am pushing is a json record with few properties like email, phone, name.
The problem I am having is I cannot make the search work properly with email addresses. I need to search in all fields (because my search parameter is generic, it's basically coming from an input). So I decided to use a multi_match like below:
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "name@host",
      "fields": ["*"]
    }
  }
  , "_source": "{_id}"
}

The above doesn't seem to work, most likely because of the "at" sign. If I search only "name" in the query, I get one hit. If I search "name@host" (so exact match) I get thousand hits. It's as if the "at" sign acts like a tokenizer, and the result contains hits with "name" and hits with "host". I confirmed this by searching "name@hostxx" which only resulted in 1 hit, the correct one.
Does anyone know how I can configure the search to use the value as an exact search? or perhaps escape the @ sign to not be interpreted as tokenizer?

I managed to find the solution, and that is to search not within the field itself (which internally is tokenized by OpenSearch in multiple smaller pieces) but rather searching the keyword. Searching the keyword is basically an exact search (which is what I need) and it's also much faster.
